Running 2 Macros with One Key combination
I'm trying to run 2 macros with one key combination. In my example, ctrl s. I've been trying but getting nowhere:( I'm creating the .ahk file with Pullover's Macro. In my example, I'm having to use 2 key presses, ctrl s, and ctrl h. I'd like to able to to toggle the 2 macros with one key press. Any help would be much appreciated:)
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#WinActivateForce
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
^h::
Macro1:
WinHide, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ahk_exe chrome.exe
Sleep, 333
Return
^s::
Macro2:
WinShow, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ahk_exe chrome.exe
Sleep, 333
Return
F8::ExitApp
F12::Pause


^s::
    toggle := !toggle   ;   EVERY Ctrl+s will change toggle from 1 to 0 and vice versa
    if  toggle          ;   if toggle has any value rather then 0
        WinShow, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Else
        WinShow, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Sleep, 333
Return

F8::ExitApp
F12::Pause

